# Get Logged In User (Current User's)'s Information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have user information stored like this in my table:

```
ID(PK) |  Email     | Pass | DepartmentID
 1      abc@g.com    hash    301
 2      abcd@g.com   hash    302
 3      abcd@g.com   hash    303
```

Now , I need to get current user's (logged in user's ) Department ID via a jQuery getJson Call from the view side but cannot find any suitable approach to do so.

My Script(snippet) in view is something like :

```
   var url="@Url.Action("Details","Users")";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){

       $("#DeptID").val(data.DepartmentID);

});
```

And My code in controller (snippet) is:

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    var user = User.Identity.Name;
    return Json(user, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Please help with an appropriate method.
Thank You.

Comment: What are you using to manage Authentication/Identity?

Comment: just use the `AspUserClaims` table. i think it will the suitable for u

Comment: @anand Currently I am using  fetching username from `User.Identity.Name` and then I am using the`AspNetUSers` to get the Department ID. Just wanted an efficient way without requesting again and again from the database.

Comment: if u use user claims, on user register, u save data in claims table, hen the user logged in you can get the data in claim table which has record for the respective user in view itself, there is no job for json or controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your derived `ApplicationUser/IdentityUser` has the properties you described in your original post

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(){
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
    //retrieve user based on some identifier.
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    object result = new object();
    if (user != null) {
        //construct a result with the data you want to send to the client.
        result = new {
            Email = user.Email,
            DepartmentID = user.DepartmentID,
        }
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: if you use `await` your method must be `async`.

Comment: Also , Identity stores Name for `UserName` field. not email as in your explanation.

Comment: @Nkosi should it be `UserManager` or `userManager`. Both of them don't work anyway. I have included AspNet.Identity .Also  `//Code here to retrieve user based on some identifier.` We already retrieved it in username, didn't we ?

Comment: @shubhamr `User.Identity` is `IPrincipal.Identity` which wont have the properties you want to access unless you had attached claims (which is another topic in itself)

Comment: As for `UserManager` or `userManager`, I am making an assumption based on your code snippet as I don't know what your controller looks like.

Comment: @Nkosi `UserManager` is a part of AspNet.Identity wheras `userManager` should be a variable I think.

Comment: Well in that case I am using a variable `userManager` which would have been set when the controller was instantiated.